# What's the English translation for "Tomate Canario"?

Tags: identification, tomatoes, cultivar

What's the correct translation in English for "Tomate Canario" (Spanish)?

I got two links in Spanish about the history of this tomato cultivar

- http://www.revistabinter.com/2017/06/19/cultivo-tomate-canario/
- http://tomatecanario.es

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: In general names are not consistent (also inside a country). Also if you get a translation, few people will understand it.  And tomatoes tend to have new varieties (replacing old one) quite frequently. Note: many producers give new names just for marketing.

Comment: The picture is very pretty but gives no idea of scale

Answer (score 1):

The Spanish literal translation is Canary Tomato which makes sense based on the articles you cited; tomatoes from the Canary Islands. If you want to go further and translate the name Canaria as in Islas Canaria, it is believed to come from the latin word for dog, canis. So, maybe it's a Dog Tomato. Take your pick.

Comment: But, Tim, the OP, I believe, meant to find out the cultivar name used in english-speaking countries.

Comment: The first link says (in Spanish) "The fact that the English merchants were in charge of selling the Canarian tomato.." - that means this cultivar is known in England, or at least it was known, some time ago. I wonder how they call it at the hypermarkets in the UK